# Cognitive Services Speech Translation as a JSON Conversation?

Tags: c#, json, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

Good morning,
I'm experimenting with Azure Cognitive Services and have a C# application that will monitor for wav files dropped into a storage account. When a file arrives, Cognitive Services will convert the text to speech.  However, the Result.Text is just one long string.
I have seen examples where CS is smart enough to differentiate between individuals on the call and store the output in json format. I can't, however, find any code examples.

**Here is an example of that I get out of test file between 2 people:**

---

*Hi. Thank you for calling Hotel California. This is Candice. How may I help you? Hi, Candice, this is Steven. I'd like to book for four people, please. And that would be for August 18th. Sure. Steven, I'd be happy to help you with that. So which room do you have in mind? Actually, I gotta tell you first that I am super busy. Mm-hmm. So I haven't been able to browse through your website and I don't know, I don't really know the rooms you have right now, but I could give you my requirements and then you suggest the best rooms for me.*

---

**What I'd like to see something like this:**

---

*Hi. Thank you for calling Hotel California. This is Candice.*

*Hi, Candice, this is Steven. I'd like to book for four people, please.*

---

Does anyone has experience using Cognitive Services to create a json conversation file?

Here is my current solution...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd7NB.jpg)

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: @pdx_boats please share the code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Cognitive Services Speech SDK does provide the ability to differentiate between speakers in a conversation. However, the example you provided doesn't seem to use the **Conversation Transcription Feature**.

To get required output, you can use the `conversation transcription with diarization` that can help in distinguish between speakers and provide output with Speaker ID.

Below is sample code using `ConversationTranscriber Function` to get Speaker ID for each individual.

```cs
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Transcription;

class Program 
{
    static string speechKey = "";
    static string speechRegion = "";
    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filepath = "katiesteve.wav";
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion);        
        speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

        var stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        using (var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(filepath))
        {
            using (var conversationTranscriber = new ConversationTranscriber(speechConfig, audioConfig))
            {
                conversationTranscriber.Transcribed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Speaker ID = {e.Result.SpeakerId}: Text = {e.Result.Text} ");
                    }
                    else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be transcribed.");
                    }
                };
                conversationTranscriber.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.");
                    stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                };
                await conversationTranscriber.StartTranscribingAsync();
                Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });
                await conversationTranscriber.StopTranscribingAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]
For sample code and other details, you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/get-started-stt-diarization?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#diarization-from-file-with-conversation-transcription).